# Qt compiling error on mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am compiling my QT 5.3.2 project in QtCreator and the compile output

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -I/usr/local/include -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I../userinterface -I../../Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I../../Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/martin/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib -o figure.o ../userinterface/figure.cpp
clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)
make: *** [figure.o] Error 1
17:06:35: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project userinterface (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
17:06:35: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Mac OS : 10.10.2
I have tried to use -stdlib=libstdc++ instead of -stdlib=libc++ but it seems does not work.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can't use c++11 for a 10.7 deployment target. Remove `CONFIG += c++11` from your project file, or choose a different compiler.

Comment: Hello, I am not add CONFIG += c++11 on my file.

Comment: I think there was a bug in Qt 5.3.* (or QtCreator distributed with it) regarding support for MacOS X 10.10.x and it's Xcode toolchain. Try upgrading your Qt to 5.4.1 and see if it helps.

Comment: thx, it is work when I upgrade Qt to 5.4.1